# Trouble installing Powercli 11.x

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

Easing back into Windows after a 3-4 year MacOS hiatus. Powershell has come a long way but I am running into some errors I can't figure out here.

Every article I see on installing the newer PowerCLI is rather simple. Use a package manager to download/install it and off you run.  Not for me, I'm getting the following error when trying to run `Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI`:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to find dependent module(s) (VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.0.4\PSModule.psm1:9307 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToFindDependencyPackage,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I have tried this on two Windows machines and even with Powershell Core on a Mac. Same issue every time. What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, and it probably won't, I'm having the exact same problem today.  Also tried on two different servers, one 2012 R2 and one 2016.  Same error.  Tried loading the Cis.Core module directly.  Got it to install, but yet still get the same error saying it's missing.  I might submit a ticket to VMware about it.  I'll let you know if I get a resolution.

Comment: I and a few others having the same problem were able to engage with VMware through Slack and the problem has been resolved.  Try installing again.

Comment: Can you give me an idea what the problem was?  I've tried multiple times on multiple systems.  I cannot get powercli installed.  I am really missing the standalone MSI now.

Comment: There was a dependency issue with the PowerShell Gallery, but that was resolved within a couple hours. What errors are you seeing now?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can download the zip file containing all the modules from the PowerCLI page on VMware Code: https://code.vmware.com/web/dp/tool/vmware-powercli/ Though, I would still recommend getting it working through PowerShell Gallery if at all possible.